# Passing char array to file using for-loop

Tags: c, string, for-loop, file-io, char

I am just learning how to work with file IO and I am probably super wrong. I need to create and write to a file a list of city names and its population density.I am able to print the list properly formatted in standard output using a for-loop, but am unable to write it to the file. Like I said when using a printf statement, it works just fine, but the (fopen, "w") fprintf isnt working. Where am I going wrong?

```
   printf("Create new file name:\n");
   scanf("%s", outfile);

   fp = fopen(outfile, "w");
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        fprintf("%s  %.2f\n", veg[i].name, density );
    }



    fclose(fp);
```

I expect the file to be populated with the list of cities, but I the program is crashing instead. I receive this error message.

"Incompatible pointer types passing 'char [10]' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *')"

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "...`

Comment: And don't forget to the check the return code from the `fopen` call. You shouldn't assume the file was opened.

Comment: I love stackoverflow! Thank you @KamilCuk

Comment: `if( fp ) { //write to file} else { printf("Failed to open file");}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the file to write in in your fprintf() call. 
`fprintf(outfile,"%s  %.2f\n", veg[i].name, density );`

Here's the doc : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

You also need to return whether or not your fopen failed.

```
if (fp != NULL)
{
    printf("File created successfully!\n");
}
else {
    printf("Unable to create file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Be aware that if you use Visual studio, you'd have to use `fprintf_s()` instead where you'd have to specify the sizeof your string.